# can you run R commands within a python chunk (using reticulate) in Rstudio?

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate

Hi smart people of the internet:

I have a rmarkdown file with R and python chunks in it. I want to write a function or two in my python chunks that can affect my global environment in R. I know you can execute python strings within an R chunk but is there a converse?

Here is what I'm talking about:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
df <- iris
``
````

````
```{python}
df = r.df

# do something in R now such as `new.R.df <- py$df` or even just run any R function such as `View(iris)`
``
````

Thank you thank you thank you =)

Comment: Why not just make a new R chunk?

Comment: Because it's annoying to have to run two chunks every time I wanna make a change to the Python code. First world problem, I realize... =)